# Invoking Function in Javascript without parentheses ()

Tags: javascript, function, invocation

Case 1:

```
function square(x) { return x*x; }
var s = square(); // Invoking with parentheses 
console.log(square(2));
console.log(s(2));
```

Case 2:

```
function square(x) { return x*x; }
var s = square;// invoking without parentheses 
console.log(square(2));
console.log(s(2));
```

Functions are always supposed to be invoked with (). Then why does it return undefined in case 1 , but works fine in Case 2?

Comment: The invocation happens in the expression `s(2)`, not in `s = square`!? There's no argument as well.

Comment: Getting `Unhandled Error: 's' is not a function` for your Case 1.

Answer (score 3):

In Case 1 you assign the *return value* of invoking ('calling') the `square` function to `s`. But since you didn't provide any parameters you are asking it to calculate `undefined * undefined`, which is `NaN` ("Not a Number", i.e. cannot be calculated).  Then at the end where you do `s(2)` I assume you get an error, because `s` is not a function.

In Case 2 you are not calling the function, you are only assigning the *function object* itself to `var s`. This means it works when you do `s(2)` because `s` is a reference to the `square` function.

Comment: Like delegates in C#?

Comment: I have no idea, but probably not the same thing... the point is that in Javascript a function is a type of object like any other.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `s` to the output of `square()` in case 1. Thus, you are passing in nothing, and assigning `s` to `undefined`.

Assign `s` to `square`, **without** parentheses `()` works because you are assigning `s` to the function `square`, and not its output.

Answer (score 1):

Here case 2 works - please check the comments for better understanding,

```
Case 1:

function square(x) { return x*x; }
var s = square(); // Invoking without any parameter
console.log(square(2));//Invoking the actual function here with param
console.log(s(2));//This is incorrect as s is storing the result of the `square()`. So this doesn't work
Case 2:

function square(x) { return x*x; }
var s = square;// just declaring a variable
console.log(square(2));//Invoking the actual function here
console.log(s(2));//Invoking the actual function here with param. It works here
```